# C++ compare two strings bad code

Tags: c++, compare

I have problem with my code.. i dont know what is wrong.. I need compare two strings. Error message:
error:'outputFile' does not name a type.

I am working with files.. write some text into it... My code for compare:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if (PorovnaniKategorie(ArrayOfWorlds[i],"mzda")==true){
//do some code
            }
            }
        }
```

Function:

```
bool PorovnaniKategorie(string s1, string s2){
    bool porovnani1=true;
    int vel1 = s1.size();
    int vel2 = s2.size();
if (vel1 == vel2)
                    {
                    for ( int i = 0; i < vel1; i++)
                    {
                        if(tolower(s1[i])!= tolower(s2[i]))
                           porovnani1 = false;
                          }
                    }
else{
    porovnani1 = false;
}
return porovnani1;
}
```

It is working separately and when i delete for cycle from main function, all is working.. I dont know how to solve this problem..

In fact i need just compare if value at index i compare to "mzda"

edit:

```
outputFile << "</body>" << endl;  //this line is error
        outputFile << "</html>" << endl;
        outputFile.close();
```

I dont think  error is here.. (this code is under for). When i delete for all is working

Comment: Is the code you show really the code that causes the error? Because there's no `outputFile` in the code you show. If you get build-errors, the compiler will include file-name *and* line-number where the error is, sometimes even function name to help you.

Comment: Your compare code (for loop) has more end braces than start braces, although it's a bit hard to see with the indentation being off.

Comment: How do you declare outputFile?

Answer (score 1):

Correct one. And please ask in google "std string compare ignore case".

```
bool PorovnaniKategorie( string s1, string s2 )
{
    if( s1.size() == s2.size() ) {
        for( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++ ) {
            if( tolower( s1[i] ) != tolower( s2[i] ) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please give full example, what is outputFile.